# ADC with Raspberry Pi (16 or 24 bits) with sampling rate of at least 1 MHz

Tags: analog-to-digital

Is it possible to use Raspberry Pi 2 to construct an acquisition system that is at least 1 MHz fast and with 24 bits (or 16 if 24 not possible)? Just 1 channel suffices!

Everything I find is either slow or low bit number. Do you know of any way to create 24-bit 1+ MHz acquisition system with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I suppose so.  I doubt the Pi would be doing very much though, perhaps switching the external acquisition system on and off.  Could you give details of the circuit you plan to use to acquire useful 24 bit data?  That equate to 0.29 microvolts with a 5V range.

Comment: While it can be done, you will need a lot of experience to build a circuit electrically quiet enough for more than 16 bits (if even that many) to be meaningful, so you are probably in buy rather than build territory (even there many budget systems are 12-bit).  In terms of getting data into the pi, USB has the bandwidth, the question is more if the pi (and whatever software stack you choose) can operate the bus close enough to its potential to do this.  You may benefit from a substantial FIFO buffer in your hardware.

Comment: I'll close-vote this question as too broad (as there are too many aspects to be addressed, many of which are not Pi specific and should be taken to electrical engineering).